# Apache Derby Concatenate Colum values on Group By

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

what I want to do is the following:

I have a table like this:

```
ID;    STATUS;    ORIGIN
1      READY      a
2      READY      b
3      OPEN       a
4      OPEN       a
```

This should be queried to:

```
IDS;   OPEN; READY; ORIGIN
1,3,4  2     1      a
2      0     1      b
```

The query so far:

```
SELECT ORIGIN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPEN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = 'READY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS READY,
  <LIST_FUNC>(ID, ',') AS IDS
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ORIGIN;
```

I am looking for a function in derby (`<LIST_FUNC>`), that does the concatenation of the ID column during the group by aggregation. Of course, the signature may look different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Derby has a function equivalent to `string_agg()` or `group_concat()`. If you really need that, you need to [implement your own](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqljcreateaggregate.html#rrefsqljcreateaggregate) or switch to HSQLDB or H2. Both have `group_concat()` for that. With HSQLDB you could even use the more concise `count(*) filter (where status = 'OPEN')` for the conditional aggregation

Comment: Ok, thanks! Derby again...